# minimum_number_should_match not working in Elasticsearch New version

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

Hi all I am using Elastic Search for retrieve data. I got error which is as follow: -

```
{
 "error": {
    "root_cause": [
        {
            "type": "parsing_exception",
            "reason": "[bool] query does not support [minimum_number_should_match]",
            "line": 1,
            "col": 396
        }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[bool] query does not support [minimum_number_should_match]",
    "line": 1,
    "col": 396
},
"status": 400
}
```

For this i have write code:

```
{
"_source": [
    "ch",
    "text",
    "title",
    "d_name"
],
"track_scores": true,
"sort": [
    "_score"
],
"size": 50,
"from": 0,
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "match_phrase": {
                    "text": {
                        "query": "xxx",
                        "slop": 5
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "match_phrase": {
                    "title": {
                        "query": "xxx",
                        "slop": 0,
                        "boost": 9
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "match_phrase": {
                    "ch": {
                        "query": "xxxx",
                        "slop": 0,
                        "boost": 15
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "minimum_number_should_match": 1,
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "d_name": "The  Central"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

}

It working fine on old version but not working on New version. and if i remove "minimum_number_should_match" then it give incorrect result and also if i use "minimum_should_match" then it gave me those record in which query value not found.

Comment: It should be `minimum_should_match`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`minimum_should_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html) parameter instead of `minimum_number_should_match`

**Update 1:**

Based on the comments below the search query will be

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "supply",
          "fields": [
            "chapters",
            "title",
            "text"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "id": "1215"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't gave me accurate record. it aslo gave those record which "xxx" not found

Comment: @RajasthanAyurvedUniversity can you please explain your use case with some sample index data and please share your expected search result as well

Comment: {"_source":["chapters","title","comment","text","doc","name"],"track_scores":true,"sort":   ["_score"],"size":50,"from":0,"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"match_phrase":{"text":{"query":"supply","slop":3}}},{"match_phrase":{"title":{"query":"supply","slop":0,"boost":3}}},{"match_phrase":{"chapters":{"query":"supply","slop":0,"boost":5}}}],"minimum_should_match":1,"filter":{"bool":{"should":[{"term":{"id":"12"}}]}}}},"highlight":{"fields":{"text":{},"title":{}}}}

Comment: index are -> title, comment, text, doc, name
there are near about 1000 record. I want atleast one "supply" match in ('title','text','chapter') in every id

Comment: But it also gave me id = "12" record in which "supply" not found

Comment: @RajasthanAyurvedUniversity this is the search query that you have shared, can you please share 1 sample index data as well that should have match this query?

Comment: client not provide me but if you want result then i will provide you

Comment: @RajasthanAyurvedUniversity ohh ok, then please share some sample result

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qnf7qPwnDhb7UpjXuPlXpouGkEmLibqJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: any thing progress?

Comment: @RajasthanAyurvedUniversity yes, I tried with three sample data (from the search result) you provided and I am getting correct results. In the result all the documents have `"id": 1215`, but in the comments above you mentioned `"id": 12`. Can you send me the result which is mismatching according to you ?

Comment: for "supply" keyword, "id": 1215 -> correct record 49
sorry for id - 12 for seccurity issue

Comment: @RajasthanAyurvedUniversity I am not getting, what do you mean by **correct record 49** ?

Comment: I got record 65 as array which is wrong correct record are 49

Comment: Can you please provide me query(json) so i can check

Comment: @RajasthanAyurvedUniversity you have to search for `supply` in three fields i.e `chapters`, `title` and `text`. Correct ? Is there any other filter you want to apply ?

Comment: Yes "filter":{"bool":{"should":[{"term":{"id":"1215"}}]} it is compulsory

Comment: Can you post query

Comment: @RajasthanAyurvedUniversity added the query. Please go through the updated part and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: it give me same record when i use minimum_should_match. also gave record in which "supplies / supplied " keyword exist.

Comment: it give me same record when i use minimum_should_match. also gave record in which "supplies / supplied " keyword exist not "supply".